# named pipes connection with IP address

Tags: c++, windows

I have funny problem that I can connect to a remote named pipe using the machine name, but it would not work with the IP address. After reading the doc on pipe names at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365783(v=vs.85).aspx - there seems to be no indication of IP address.

Although, I know IP address work for pipe name (worked when I used Windows 2008R2, but didn't work when the pipe was created on Windows 2003).

So are IP address supported? Are they supported on certain OS? 
Firewall is off, and everything I can think of is setup OK considering the pipe works with the machine name....

BTW. I am using C++ unmanaged to work with the pipes.

Comment: are you controlling both ends?  for example, in SQL server you can have named pipes enabled and tcp/ip disabled

Comment: "Would not work": what symptoms are you getting? What pipe name are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Named Pipes operate at a different layer of the network protocol stack. Named Pipes work only on the local network where Windows name services are available, and are not routed using TCP / IP.

When you thought you were creating a named pipe using an IP address, you may have been creating a pipe that used a ###.###.###.### as a pipe name instead of as a server name.  CreateNamedPipe can only create a pipe on the local machine, not on a remote machine.  And it requires a "\\.\" prefix on the front of the pipe name.