# What is the local IP used for a named pipe connection?

Tags: winapi, networking, named-pipes

*This is NOT even close to a duplicate of [named pipes connection with IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084805/named-pipes-connection-with-ip-address)*

A Windows C++ application on a local system with multiple adapters and IP addresses that connects to a remote system using a named pipe by name.   How do you find out which IP address was used to establish the connection?

To understand the question more:

- I know how to get all the local systems adapters and IP addresses.
- I know how to create and connect to named pipes on both ends.

What I need to know is:

- How do you know which adapter (hence the IP or network) was used for the named pipe connection?

There are multiple networks and adapters involved here.

Comment: Named pipes don't use IP addresses